# How do I fix syntax error in JOIN statement while using SQL to query Excel spreadsheet?

Tags: sql, excel, jet

I have an Excel workbook that contains several spreadsheets. I need to pull data from them using Jet SQL for a desktop application. I can query individual tables without a problem, but when I try to use a statement that requires a join, it gives me a generic Syntax Error in the JOIN statement. The query I'm having trouble with is:

```
SELECT      [Subscribed Email IDs].PIN
        ,   [Subscribed Email IDs].[Email Id]
        ,   [SubscriptionList].[Dealer Account]
        ,   [SubscriptionList].[Dealer Name] 
FROM        [Subscribed Email IDs$B4:C30000] 
INNER JOIN  [SubscriptionList$B4:J30000] 
ON          [Subscribed Email IDs].[PIN]        = [SubscriptionList].[Pin Txt] 
WHERE       [Subscribed Email IDs].[Email Id]   = '<email address value here...>'
```

I have to use ranges, because the spreadsheet has extra rows at the top that do not contain either headers or data, and the 'A' column contains nothing. I have tried without the ranges, and I get the same error, so I think it is something more basic with the way I have written the query. What am I missing?

Comment: what error message do you get?

Comment: OleDbException was unhandled: Syntax error in JOIN operation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a different range variable in your `ON` clause:

```
 ... FROM [Subscribed Email IDs$B4:C30000]
 ... ON [Subscribed Email IDs].[PIN]
```

I suggest you use shorter range variables e.g. `T`:

```
 ... FROM [Subscribed Email IDs$B4:C30000] AS T
 ... ON T.[PIN]
```